# Understanding "perimeter" invariant

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, invariance

During 6.042, the students are sitting in an $n$ × $n$ grid. A sudden outbreak of beaver flu
(a rare variant of bird flu that lasts forever; symptoms include yearning for problem sets
and craving for ice cream study sessions) causes some students to get infected. Here is an
example where $n = 6$ and infected students are marked ×.

[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4omPZ.png)

Now the infection begins to spread every minute (in discrete time-steps). Two students are
considered adjacent if they share an edge (i.e., front, back, left or right, but NOT diagonal);
thus, each student is adjacent to $2, 3,$ or $4$ others. A student is infected in the next time step
if either:

- the student was previously infected (since beaver flu lasts forever), or
- the student is adjacent to at least two already-infected students.

In the example, the infection spreads as shown below.

[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4L8Q.png)

In this example, over the next few time-steps, all the students in class become infected.

**Theorem.** If fewer than $n$ students in class are initially infected, the whole class will never
be completely infected.

Prove this theorem.

*Hint: When one wants to understand how a system such as the above “evolves” over time,
it is usually a good strategy to (1) identify an appropriate property of the system at the
initial stage, and (2) prove, by induction on the number of time-steps, that the property is
preserved at every time-step. So look for a property (of the set of infected students) that
remains invariant as time proceeds.*

[Source: MIT OCW Mathematics for Computer Science, Problem Set 2, Problem 3.](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/assignments/MIT6_042JF10_assn02.pdf)

Unfortunately, I could not solve this problem and had to look up the solution. But even after looking at the solution, the whole thing doesn't make complete sense to me. I think I might be misunderstanding what [perimeter means](https://github.com/frevib/mit-cs-math-6042-fall-2010-problems/blob/master/ps2-sol.pdf) (Define the perimeter of an infected set of students to be the number of edges with infection on exactly one side). I currently have two problems in understanding the solution -

1. When I calculate the perimeter of the infected students in the starting state, I get 30, when I should be getting n*4 = 6*4 = 24. [Here's how.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1ND9.jpg)
2. The solution also states that for every infected student added, the edges subtracted from the perimeter of the previous state is neutralized by the edges of the new infected student. [What about this case?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bfd9.jpg)

Also, as a more general question, how does one go about identifying the invariant property for such questions?

Comment: The link with what I assume contains the solution gets me to a github site ... but no text. Could you maybe copy and paste the relevant passage as text into your post? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about the link. I've added the definition of perimeter according to the solution. I admit, my understanding of what it means is probably wrong, and hence all this confusion. If you could explain what that perimeter is, and/or how to calculate it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: OK, so I now think that in the example you were right, and that the perimeter is $30$, i.e. You *do* count the edges on the edge of the board. As such, you should be able show that the perimeter will always remain below $4k$, with $k$ being the initial number of infected students. I think with that you can fill in the details of the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I think is going on:

In the example, the inital perimeter really is $30$. But, maybe the invariant is not that the perimeter always stays the same .... but that it always stays *below* $4n$. So, the fact that in your example the perimeter decreases would be just fine ... as long as it does not increase, then if the perimeter at the start is below $4n$ (which it is if there are fewer than $n$ initially infected students) it will never reach $4n$ ... which is what the perimeter of a 'full' board is. So, to complete the proof, you have to show that the condition under which new students get infected means that the perimeter either stays the same or decreases.

As to your last question: Ha! If only mathematicians had a formula for finding invariants! No, I think this only comes with practice.

Comment: Thank you! When counting the edges in the second state given in the example, I get 20, discounting the edges that are part of the n*n square grid. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ApoorvaAnand I should have made clear that I actually don't know how perimeter is defined ....

Comment: Of course!!! Thank you. I made a terribly silly mistake where the solution stating "the perimeter never increases" became "the perimeter always remains the same" in my head. Everything makes sense now.

Comment: @ApoorvaAnand Right ... but who said that the perimeter had to be $24$ in your example? That threw me for quite a loop... Anyway, thanks for the problem; it was fun trying to figure it out! :)

Comment: Because I thought the perimeter remained the same, the start state should have obviously had same perimeter as the final state which I knew to be n*4. This is why I thought I was calculating the perimeter of the states incorrectly

Comment: @ApoorvaAnand Ah, of course, that makes total sense! :)